# Best way to work with a public Git repository

Tags: git, github, version-control

I want to use one of the public git repositories and make my changes. However, since these changes are only private to me, I do not want to merge these back to the original repository. Also I am not sure if these changes would be accepted in public repo.

I know that one can commit the changes to the local copy/repo and if required, push the changes to the original repo. However, this has a danger of losing the changes in case something goes wrong with your local committed copy, so push is required.

So far, I am using a copy of the code (zip file that git provides), and checking it in into my private repository. This way,  I am completely independent and also able to push the changes to cloud. Now the implication is that I am deprived of any updates that are happening and sync'ing with it a painful task, or I do not sync at all.

Can someone please suggest a way out of this so that I am able to push my changes to my repo (in my git account), and also be able to sync whatever updates coming along. Does branching helps in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just [fork it](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/).  Then keep merging from upstream to get changes.